# Lisp error: (error "Lisp nesting exceeds `max-lisp-eval-depth'") when using cl- functions

Tags: emacs, packages, lisp

I recently moved computers *and* upgraded to Emacs 24.3 (from 24.2) yesterday.
Since then, I have been receiving what is essentially a stack-overflow error:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Lisp nesting exceeds `max-lisp-eval-depth'")
  position(...)
  apply(position ...)
  position(...)
  apply(position ...)

  position(nil (#<buffer ssa.org> #<buffer  *Minibuf-1*> #<buffer  *Minibuf-0*> #<buffer  *code-conversion-work*> #<buffer  *Echo Area 0*> #<buffer  *Echo Area 1*> #<buffer  *doc-view conversion output*> #<buffer  *autoload*> #<buffer  *canonical address*> #<buffer  *extract address components*> #<buffer *Messages*>) :if #[(buf) "rq\210 \203\n    =\2051\306!\f\232\2051\307\310\311
!\"\312 \313\314\315#,)\207" [buf mode major-mode default-directory topdir name expand-file-name format "^%s\\(?:<[0-9]+>\\)?$" regexp-quote buffer-name nil t string-match start string regexp inhibit-changing-match-data] 4])
  apply(position nil (#<buffer ssa.org> #<buffer  *Minibuf-1*> #<buffer  *Minibuf-0*> #<buffer  *code-conversion-work*> #<buffer  *Echo Area 0*> #<buffer  *Echo Area 1*> #<buffer  *doc-view conversion output*> #<buffer  *autoload*> #<buffer  *canonical address*> #<buffer  *extract address components*> #<buffer *Messages*>) (:if #[(buf) "rq\210  \203\n    =\2051\306!\f\232\2051\307\310\311
!\"\312 \313\314\315#,)\207" [buf mode major-mode default-directory topdir name expand-file-name format "^%s\\(?:<[0-9]+>\\)?$" regexp-quote buffer-name nil t string-match start string regexp inhibit-changing-match-data] 4]))

  ...
  ...
  ...

  position(...)
  apply(position ...)
  position(...)
  apply(position ...)
  cl-position(...)
  apply(cl-position ...)
  cl-find(...)
  apply(cl-find ...)
  cl-find-if(...)
  magit-mode-get-buffer("*magit: %t*" magit-status-mode nil t)
  magit-mode-get-buffer-create("*magit: %t*" magit-status-mode)
  magit-mode-display-buffer("*magit: %t*" magit-status-mode pop-to-buffer)
  magit-status("/Users/sean/Dropbox/smp/")
  call-interactively(magit-status)
  (lambda nil (interactive) (call-interactively (quote magit-status)))()
  call-interactively((lambda nil (interactive) (call-interactively (quote magit-status))) nil nil)
```

I suspect that this is an issue with the `cl` bundle in 24.3 as I have seen this recently in a different package (though I cannot remember which).

- Is this a common problem when upgrading?
- What can I do to resolve this?

The full log file (kind of huge) is available [here](http://pastebin.com/5ed40Jgy) for anyone who wishes to inspect it, but I hope that I have inlined the necessary details in this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a problem with a circular definition.

I think the problem is that you compiled magit with the previous version of emacs; you should recompile magit with the new emacs and the problem will disappear.

Comment: Deleting both `cl-lib` and `magit`, closing emacs, re-opening and re-installing `magit` (only) did the trick.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I suppose this is cl-lib problem. If you already installed cl-lib via package.el,
you should uninstall cl-lib and try again. Emacs 24.3 bundles cl-lib.el. cl-lib
package is for older Emacs(< 24.3).

Comment: I just wanted to say thank you for this answer—it was still pretty instrumental in resolving :) I only accepted the other answer because it gave a why (and because I never would have thought I needed to re-install `magit` for this).  I regret that I have but one upvote to give!